# Are an Isitoq's Daze & Tears of Anguish the same thing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, familiars, difficulty-class, daze

[image: Isitoq]

The [Isitoq](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/isitoq), the wonderful Undead Eye available as an [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar)<sup>1</sup>. It has two abilities that appear to be... the same:

> **Daze (Ex):** An isitoq's nerves form grotesque wings. Any creature struck by the creature's wings must succeed at a DC 11 Will save or be
>   dazed for 1 round as the target's mind is flooded with images of the
>   last seconds of the isitoq's existence as a living creature. This is a
>   mind-affecting fear effect. The save DC is Charisma-based.
>
> **Tears of Anguish (Su:)** As a full-round action, an isitoq can make a ranged touch attack to squirt tears into the eyes of a creature
>   within 30 feet. If the target fails a DC 11 saving throw, it
>   experiences the effect of the isitoq's daze ability. The save DC is
>   Charisma-based.

---

Daze is very cut and dry. Tears of Anguish though, specifically says it experiences the Daze ability. Daze is (Ex) and Tears of Anguish is (Su), though, so there is a separation in delivery, but not really in method. The reason this is important, is for the purposes of the feat [Ability Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/ability-focus).

**Would I need Ability Focus for each ability, or just Daze, since Tears of Anguish<sup>2</sup> produces the effect of Daze?**

---

I can internally argue it both ways. I just would like to know what those here on RPG.SE have to say in order to make a more informed decision.

Swapping out [Weapon Finesse](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat---final) for Ability Focus is a no-brainer, since Diminutive creatures can use Dexterity to hit anyway<sup>3</sup>, as a [familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar).

- <sup>1</sup><sub>An evil spellcaster with the Improved Familiar feat
  can gain an isitoq as a familiar at 5th level.</sub>
- <sup>2</sup><sub>If the target fails a DC 11 saving throw, it
  experiences the effect of the isitoq's daze ability.</sub>
- <sup>3</sup><sub>Use the familiar's Dexterity or Strength modifier, whichever is greater, to calculate the familiar's melee attack bonus with natural weapons.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Isitoq's **Daze** is delivered as part of its wing attack :

> 2 wings +6 (1d1–3 plus daze) ;

While its **Tears of Anguish** is a special attack, a full-round action ranged touch attack which delivers the same ***effects*** as its **Daze**, i.e. :

> be dazed for 1 round as the target's mind is flooded with images of
>   the last seconds of the isitoq's existence as a living creature.

I understand the doubt that could arise, however they are different abilities, even though they have the same effect.

**Tears of Anguish** :

> If the target fails a DC 11 saving throw, it experiences the effect of
>   the isitoq's daze ability.

The fact that both special attacks have different saving throws means that *Ability Focus* would affect only one of them. If you're hit by **Tears of Anguish**, you don't get a second saving throw from **Daze**.

You'd need two *Ability Focus*.